# synchronous execution in loopback io

Tags: node.js, cassandra, loopbackjs

I am using Cassandra nodejs connector in loopback io framework. Since loopback do not have a inbuild cassandra connector I am using nodejs cassandra connector. Also I am using remotehook in loopback to call my custom method when calling a rest api. In the beforeremote() method i need to validate few inputs from api through my cassandra db tables.

I have 3 inputs keys in rest api which needs to be validated in cassandra 3 tables for which I have created 3 methods. The problem is I need to validate it one by one and I have asynchronous methods in cassandra. How can I achieve this in synchronous ways as all three validations should go one after the other in a synchrnous way. I can post code if need be.

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you can use `async.series()`. More details and example here: https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback